# Use iterator variable on element name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is what i have so far:

```
function listarRestaurantes(){
for(i=0; i<restaurantes.length; i++){
    if(restaurantes[i]['nombre'].length >= 0 && restaurantes[i]['nombre'].length <= 11){
        $("p.nombre_res").css('line-height', '140px');
        $("#col_derecha ul").append("<li class='restaurantes'><div><p class='nombre_res'>" + restaurantes[i]['nombre'] + "</p><p class='vermas'><a href='#'>ver más</a></p></div><img src='img/logos_restaurantes/" + restaurantes[i]['imagen'] + "'/ ></li>").css('opacity',0).animate({opacity:1}, 500);  
    }else if(restaurantes[i]['nombre'].length > 11 && restaurantes[i]['nombre'].length <= 20){
        $("p.nombre_res").css('line-height', '100px');
        $("#col_derecha ul").append("<li class='restaurantes'><div><p class='nombre_res'>" + restaurantes[i]['nombre'] + "</p><p class='vermas'><a href='#'>ver más</a></p></div><img src='img/logos_restaurantes/" + restaurantes[i]['imagen'] + "'/ ></li>").css('opacity',0).animate({opacity:1}, 500);  
    }else if(restaurantes[i]['nombre'].length > 20 && restaurantes[i]['nombre'].length <= 30){
        $("p.nombre_res").css('line-height', '60px');
        $("#col_derecha ul").append("<li class='restaurantes'><div><p class='nombre_res'>" + restaurantes[i]['nombre'] + "</p><p class='vermas'><a href='#'>ver más</a></p></div><img src='img/logos_restaurantes/" + restaurantes[i]['imagen'] + "'/ ></li>").css('opacity',0).animate({opacity:1}, 500);  
    }
}
```

}

What i'm trying to do is to add a css style to a sprecific li by calling it by it's nth-child position, so what i tryied was this:

```
$("#col_derecha ul li:nth-child(" + i+1 + ") p.nombre_res").css('line-height', '140px');
```

Of course that didn't work. I'm a beginner so my code may be very inefficient, but i'm not worried about that right now, what i want is to add a diferent line-height to each li depending on restaurantes[i]['nombre'].length.

Comment: did you try this `$("#col_derecha ul li:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ") p.nombre_res").css('line-height', '140px');` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"#col_derecha ul li:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ") p.nombre_res"
```

if `i==1` you get `i+1` as `2` now, with your solution you will get `i+1` as `11`, this is because when you try to add a string to number both are converted to strings with implicit type conversion. So force it to evaluate number part first.

Comment: This, plus moving the code line after de append code line worked just great, thank you sabithpocker and thanks to everyone who answered me! =)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of building the selector string by appending bits together, I would suggest you use the jquery `.eq` method to get the eqvivalent of the nth-child, and then use the `.find` method to match the rest of the selector.

Something like this:

```
$("#col_derecha ul li").eq(i).find('p.nombre_res').css('line-height', '140px');
```

Comment: @maurilop Updated the answer - I should have used `find` rather than `children` since the `p` isn't an immediate child of the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your logic and assign the `line-height` on each iteration of the cycle:

```
function listarRestaurantes() {
    for (i = 0; i < restaurantes.length; i++) {
        var restaurantes_len = restaurantes[i]['nombre'].length;
        var nombre_res_height = 0;
        if (restaurantes_len >= 0 && restaurantes <= 11) {
            nombre_res_height = '140px';
        } else if (restaurantes_len > 11 && restaurantes_len <= 20) {
        nombre_res_height = '100px';
        } else if (restaurantes_len  > 20 && restaurantes_len  <= 30) {
            nombre_res_height = '60px';
        }

        if(nombre_res_height){
            $("#col_derecha ul").append("<li class='restaurantes'><div><p class='nombre_res'>" + 
            restaurantes[i]['nombre'] + 
            "</p><p class='vermas'><a href='#'>ver más</a></p></div><img src='img/logos_restaurantes/" + 
            restaurantes[i]['imagen'] + "'/ ></li>").css('opacity', 0).animate({opacity: 1}, 500).find('.nombre_res').css('line_height',nombre_res_height);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you were close. Try using the :nth-of-type selector so you are only counting through the li elements rather than all elements:

```
$("#col_derecha li:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").addClass("mediumHeight");
```